# Нужно сделать возможность выкладывания на сайт поста

Tags: php, база-данных

Нужно сделать возможность выкладывания на сайт постов людьми,с возможность добавления картинок музыки текста и так далее,на php,используя базу данных,заранее спасибо.

Comment: В чем заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: Нужно чтобы зарегистрированные пользователи могли выкладывать такой контент.

Comment: @M1st7k Это мы поняли. А вопрос-то в чём? :)

Comment: нужно чтобы кто то сделал это =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делается это просто:

1. На стороне сервера создаётся метод, принимающий набор параметров поста (заголовок, текст, ссылки на файлы или сами файлы музыки, видео etc)
2. Сервер, приняв запрос складирует пришедшую информацию в БД.
3. На стороне сайта создаётся форма ввода указанных выше строк и файлов.

Если требуется отличение постов разных пользователей - требуется настроить систему аутентификации.